# Overwrite an existing plugin JS in Shopware 6

Tags: javascript, shopware, shopware6

I am currently trying to overwrite a javascript file from an existing plugin.

I've been following the [documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/override-existing-javascript) but I am struggling with the path for the JS class to overwrite.

In the docs is an example code:

```
import CookiePermissionPlugin from 'src/plugin/cookie/cookie-permission.plugin';

export default class MyCookiePermission extends CookiePermissionPlugin {
}
```

So I implemented the following code:

```
import QuantityField from 'src/plugin/FilterRangeSlider/filter-range-slider.plugin';

export default class ExampleQuantityField extends QuantityField {
```

This code does not work for me, since the original file is in the vendor directory and my plugin is in the custom directory. When trying to compile (eg `bin/build-storefront.sh`) I receive the following error message:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/plugin/FilterRangeSlider/filter-range-slider.plugin' in '<project root>/custom/plugins/ExampleProductFilter/src/Resources/app/storefront/src/filter-range-slider'

Any idea how I can import that class as stated in the docs?

Comment: In your example you paste code from the CookiePermissionPlugin - In your Error message it's the FilterRangeSlider from within the plugin. Please show the exact code which you have and not what's written within the docs.

Comment: @ChristopherDosin MweisIMI edited the question. I guess it would work to import from `../../../../(no clue how many times)/../vendor/store.shopware.com/.....` but is that a clean solution?

Comment: I think if the plugin would extend the webpack config like this: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/extending-webpack and register an alias, it would be very simple

Answer (score 4):

Node.js provides a bunch of in-built file-system functionalities. The `__dirname` points to the root directory.

So, this should work.

```js
import QuantityField from `${__dirname}/vendor/store.shopware.com/mmeesrangesliderpro/src/Resources/app/storefront/src/script/filter-range-slider.plugin`
```

Comment: Is there something like a plugin root variable, to make it portable is the plugin was installed via admin panel and not composer?

Comment: I does seem to work. with backticks I get a syntax error, without a "can't resolve"

Comment: You cannot use backticks in import, this won't work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54436091/technical-explaination-why-backtick-doesnt-work-with-import-statement

Answer (score 2):

My current solution is not really clean...

```
import QuantityField from '../../../../../../../../../vendor/store.shopware.com/mmeesrangesliderpro/src/Resources/app/storefront/src/script/filter-range-slider.plugin';
```

Isnt there any plugin root variable or something similar?

Comment: wondering if there is a better way, avoiding this series of "../"

Answer (score 0):

There is - I believe - no easier way to accomplish this.

If each plugin would extend the webpack config as described in

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/extending-webpack

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = () => {
    return {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            MmeesRangeSliderPro: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src')
        }
    }
    };
};
```

The alias could be used instead of the Plugin Root.

But this is not the case, so the following is *not* working:

```
import QuantityField from 'MmeesRangeSliderPro/plugin/FilterRangeSlider/filter-range-slider.plugin';
```

You can add a `console.log(webpackConfig)` to the bottom  of `Resources/app/storefront/webpack.config.js` to validate this.

```
   alias: {
      src: '/home/user/example/projects/example.de/vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/src',
      assets: '/home/user/example/projects/example.de/vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/assets',
      jquery: 'jquery/dist/jquery.slim',
      scss: '/home/user/example/projects/example.de/vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/src/scss',
      vendor: '/home/user/example/projects/example.de/vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/vendor'
    }
```

And those again to not really allow locating the module.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a third-party plugin, replace the path with an absolute path like the following

```
import ThirdPartyPlugin from '/app/custom/plugins/ThirdPartyPlugin/src/Resources/app/storefront/src/third-party-plugin/third-party-plugin.plugin';
```